# Springboot Hibernate - Problem with EAGER fetch type

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I develop an API for a game I am playing with Springboot 2.7.16

I stock some data in a MySql 8.0 database.

I have the following two entities :

PLAYER :

```
@Entity
public class Player {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "player_id", columnDefinition = ColumnDefinitionValue.BIGINT)
    private long playerId;

    @Column(name = "player_name", columnDefinition = ColumnDefinitionValue.VARCHAR_20)
    private String playerName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Player_Blueprint", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"), inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "blueprint_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "server_id") })
    private Set<Blueprint> blueprints = new HashSet<Blueprint>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "actionOwner", targetEntity = Action.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Action> ownedActions = new HashSet<Action>();
    
    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

ACTION :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "actions")
public class Action {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "action_id")
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "action_type")
    private ActionType actionType;

    // Problem here when I change to FetchType.EAGER
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "action_owner", nullable = false)
    private Player actionOwner;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @Basic
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "server_id", nullable = false)
    private Server server;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = ActionTypeDetails.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "action_type_details_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private ActionTypeDetails actionTypeDetails;
    
    // getters, setters, constructors
}
```

It works well until now, except I would like to stop working with proxy in my 'Action' entity. To do so, I tried to replace FetchType.LAZY by FetchType.EAGER on my 'actionOwner' atrtribute :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "action_owner", nullable = false)
private Player actionOwner;
```

When I do that, I get the folowwing error when starting the application at the initialization (I am not even trying to save data in database yet) :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.loader.OuterJoinableAssociation.getJoinableType()" because "lhs" is null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1160) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.16.jar!/:2.7.16]
        at com.spring.rustigy.Application.main(Application.java:43) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[rustigy-backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[rustigy-backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[rustigy-backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[rustigy-backend-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.loader.OuterJoinableAssociation.getJoinableType()" because "lhs" is null
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.loader.OuterJoinableAssociation.getJoinableType()" because "lhs" is null
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityJoinWalker$AssociationInitCallbackImpl.locateKeyManyToOneTargetIndex(EntityJoinWalker.java:244) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityJoinWalker$AssociationInitCallbackImpl.findKeyManyToOneTargetIndices(EntityJoinWalker.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityJoinWalker$AssociationInitCallbackImpl.resolve(EntityJoinWalker.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityJoinWalker.<init>(EntityJoinWalker.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createUniqueKeyLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2580) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createUniqueKeyLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2552) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4446) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.15.Final.jar!/:5.6.15.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.30.jar!/:5.3.30]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Someone could help me trying to understand where the problem is ? I didn't find much information about this error .. Thank you !

I tried to comment the @OneToMany annotation in my Player entity for the Set without success.